# php curl_multi_exec current executing curl name

Tags: php

Is there a way to find out which curl is being executed by the `curl_multi_exec` in this function...which is more or less provided on `php.net` ?

```
<?php
...
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the five handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch3);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch4);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch5);
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) {
        usleep(1);
    }
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}
...
?>
```

Comment: no, you need the part of code where `$mh` is defined

Comment: @Paolo $mh is just holding the different curl's, i want to know which particular curl is being executed under the curl_multi_exec when it is being executed...thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All requests are started at the first `curl_multi_exec` and then will run asyncronously.

Subsequent calls to `curl_multi_exec` in the code posted serve the purpose to periodically check if there are requests still in progress (by reading the value returned by reference into `$active`).

The value returned into `$mrc` is also checked, normally it is `CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM` (multi curl still running), or `CURLM_OK` (multi curl is done - `$active` should be `FALSE`). See http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php and search for text beginning with `CURLM_` to see all the constants related to curl multi.

**Said that your question has no answer.** All requests run in parallel then they come to an end as they are fulfilled or an error occurrs. When all requests are done the values returned by `curl_multi_exec` let the loop exit and allow the script execution to proceed.

Note however that you may call **[curl_multi_info_read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php)** to gather information about the current transfers; at the time of writing you may know which requests are done (and by exclusion which are still running);

from the manual:

> Ask the multi handle if there are any messages or information from the individual transfers. Messages may include information such as an error code from the transfer or just the fact that a transfer is completed.
>
> Repeated calls to this function will return a new result each time, until a FALSE is returned as a signal that there is no more to get at this point.

Comment: "array(3) { ["msg"]=> int(1) ["result"]=> int(0) ["handle"]=> resource(3) of type (curl) } " this is the format of output given by curl_multi_info_read ..could u pls explain it to me?..some of it makes sense to me..some of it..not so much..for instance..what is resource (6)?

Comment: @rsSpeaks it's well explained in the link to the manual I provided in the answer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php  ---   the handle in the informational associative array is the **curl handle** you create to make each request via `curl`